# LDAP Auth with mysql php sessions

Tags: php, mysql

i have a wierd issue sessions are not saving to global variable but they are saving to my database correctly. i have an ldap auth script that sets the sessions and i get logged in but when i refresh or goto a different page it loses the variables and its driving me insane here are the scripts minus the ldap_auth.php

```
<?
function sess_open($save_path, $session_name){
        $_SERVER['SessionDB']->connect();
        if ($_SERVER['SessionDB']->sess) return true;
        else return false;
}

function sess_close(){
        $_SERVER['SessionDB']->disconnect();
}

function sess_read($key){
        global $SESS_LIFE;
        $_SERVER['SessionDB']->Query('UPDATE Sessions SET Expiry="' . (time() + $SESS_LIFE) . '" WHERE SessionID="' . $key . '" AND Expiry >= "' . time() . '"');
        $Value = $_SERVER['SessionDB']->oQuery('SELECT Value FROM Sessions WHERE SessionID = "' . $key . '" AND Expiry >= ' . time());
        if ($Value) return $Value;
        else return '';
}

function sess_write($key, $val){
        global $SESS_LIFE;
        $Expiry = time() + $SESS_LIFE;
        $Value = addslashes($val);
        if (!$qid = $_SERVER['SessionDB']->Query('INSERT INTO Sessions VALUES ("' . $key . '", ' . $Expiry . ', "' . $Value . '")'))
                $qid = $_SERVER['SessionDB']->Query('UPDATE Sessions SET Expiry = ' . $Expiry . ', Value = "' . $Value . '" WHERE SessionID = "' . $key . '" AND Expiry > ' . time());

        return $qid;
}

function sess_destroy($key){
        return $_SERVER['SessionDB']->Query('DELETE FROM Sessions WHERE SessionID = "' . $key . '"');
}

function sess_gc($maxlifetime){
        return $_SERVER['SessionDB']->Query('DELETE FROM Sessions WHERE Expiry < ' . time());
}

$SESS_LIFE = get_cfg_var("session.gc_maxlifetime");
ini_set("session.save_handler", "user");
session_set_save_handler("sess_open", "sess_close", "sess_read", "sess_write", "sess_destroy", "sess_gc");

// We want a seperate one in $_SERVER['SessionDB']
$_SERVER['SessionDB'] = new mysql_db();

// Set this information appropriately based on what's in
// our configuration file
$_SERVER['SessionDB']->Hostname = $config->dbHost;
$_SERVER['SessionDB']->Username = $config->dbUser;
$_SERVER['SessionDB']->Password = $config->dbPass;
$_SERVER['SessionDB']->Database = $config->dbName;

session_start();
foreach ($_SESSION as $key=>$value)
        if (is_string($value))
                $_SESSION[$key] = trim($value);

function murder_session(){
//      session_destroy();
//      unset($_SESSION);
}
?>
```

Here is the login.php

```
<?

// check to see if user is logging out
if(isset($_GET['out'])) {
   // destroy session
    session_unset();
    unset($_SESSION['user'],$_SESSION['access']);
    session_destroy();
}

// check to see if login form has been submitted
if(isset($_POST['login_Username'])){
    // run information through authenticator
    if(authenticate($_POST['login_Username'],$_POST['login_Password']))
    {
        // authentication passed

    } else {
        // authentication failed
        $error = 1;
    }
}

// output error to user
if (isset($error)) nice_death("Login failed: Incorrect user name, password, or rights");

// output logout success
if (isset($_GET['out'])) nice_exit("Logout successful");
?>
```

Here is the includes file which includes the order in which they are loaded

```
// We prefer to use MySQL for our sessions instead of files in /tmp
// for (somewhat obvious) security reasons. Our functions to handle this
// are in here.
require_once($inc_dir . 'session.inc');

// Let's see if the user is trying to log in. We do this here because
// the login form is displayed on all pages until the user logs in.
require_once($inc_dir . 'ldap_auth.php');
require_once($inc_dir . 'login.inc');
```

Here is the ldap script

```
<?
function authenticate($user, $password) {
    // Active Directory server
    $ldap_host = "x.x.x.x";

    // Active Directory DN
    $ldap_dn = "Here is the long LDAP String";

    // Domain, for purposes of constructing $user
    $ldap_usr_dom = "@here.local";

    // connect to active directory
    $ldap = ldap_connect($ldap_host)
        or die("Couldn't connect to LDAP Server");

        $x = explode('.', $user);
        $user = $x[0] . ' ' . $x[1];

    $dn = "cn=".$user.",";

    // verify user and password
    if($bind = @ldap_bind($ldap, $dn . $ldap_dn, $password)) {
        // valid
        // check presence in groups
        $filter = "(cn=" . $user . ")";
        $attr = array("memberof");
        $result = ldap_search($ldap, $ldap_dn, $filter, $attr) or exit("Unable to search LDAP server");
        $entries = ldap_get_entries($ldap, $result);
        ldap_unbind($ldap);


        $_SESSION['user'] = $user;
       // $_SESSION['access'] = $access;
        $_SESSION['LoggedIn'] = true;

        return true;
    } else {
        // invalid name or password
        return false;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: perhaps if you used `$_SESSION`, instead of `$_SERVER`. _SERVER is for retrieving info about the system and server configuration. It's **NOT** a place you should be storing objects and/or arbitrary data

Comment: It's only `$_SERVER['SessionDB']` that's stored in `$_SERVER`. While it's still wrong and icky, that isn't the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

That's because your LDAP/login script is started before the session script and the [`session_start()`](http://php.net/session_start) call, i.e., it gets the LDAP values, it saves them to your database properly and your login works but since the session is not started yet, the stuff placed in `$_SESSION` is promptly forgotten by the next request.

Or, if the session is ok, your session [cookies may be set wrong](http://php.net/session_set_cookie_params) (to a different path, or domain, or too short of an expiry time, or any other mistake) but thats less likely.

Comment: That wasn't it, i edited the top post to show you the order in which they load and the ldap script as well.

Comment: OK so that was it i added it to the very first file it calls for the site which is is includes file, however I don't know why that would be the issue as i had it this way with a users table in the database before the ldap script and it worked fine any ideas?

Comment: I'm not quite sure if you can make a LDAP connection persist after the script has ended. In any case you are trying to store stuff in `$_SERVER`, its not place to store anything. `$_SERVER` is a superglobal for retrieving information about the server, the connection and the PHP itself, not for storing anything.

Comment: Does it need to persist? Once it saves to the SESSION variable and the database from there it should be checking the session id to ensure the user is still logged in correct?

Comment: I don't think so. The session is server controlled, if you say  `$_SESSION['logged_in'] = true` then while the session is active, `$_SESSION['logged_in']` will be set and `true` therefore the user had logged in. You usually don't have to go further, unless you want to test and drop the user session if his account was deleted or something like that.

Comment: The strange thing is once i moved the session_start() to the first thing that loads on the page it worked storing the information to the server instead of the database

Answer (score 0):

OK so i figured it out it was kind of dumb that this is the way i had to do it when the other way works fine for a users table in the database. So here is the old that works with a users table but not LDAP scripts

```
function sess_write($key, $val){
        global $SESS_LIFE, $sess_db;
        $Expiry = time() + $SESS_LIFE;
        $Value = addslashes($val);
        if (!$qid = $sess_db->Query('INSERT INTO Sessions VALUES ("' . $key . '", ' . $Expiry . ', "' . $Value . '")'))
                $qid = $sess_db->Query('UPDATE Sessions SET Expiry = ' . $Expiry . ', Value = "' . $Value . '" WHERE SessionID = "' . $key . '"
 AND Expiry > ' . time());

        return $qid;
}
```

And here is the new way i wrote it

```
function sess_write($key, $val){
        global $SESS_LIFE, $sess_db;
        $Expiry = time() + $SESS_LIFE;
        $Value = addslashes($val);

        if (!$qid = $sess_db->rQuery('SELECT * FROM Sessions WHERE SessionID = "'.$key.'" AND Expiry >=' . time())) {
                $sess_db->Query('INSERT INTO Sessions (SessionID,Expiry,Value) VALUES ("' . $key . '", ' . $Expiry . ', "' . $Value . '")');
        } else {
                $sess_db->Query('UPDATE Sessions SET Expiry = ' . $Expiry . ', Value = "' . $Value . '" WHERE SessionID = "' . $key . '"');
                if ($sess_db->Error()) die($sess_db->Error());
        }
        return $qid;
}
```

I still don't understand why one works with a users table fine but the other way works with both perfectly....

Comment: OK i actually lied , there was also the fact i didn't make SessionID a primary key.... noobie mistake